# Passing parameter via Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am working on a project and facing a problem. Can't findout what is the problem in my code.Below is my code, don't know why Ajax url can't get function ReceivedMessageByIndexNumber of default.aspx. Thank you.

JavaScript:

```
    ReceivedMessage(1);

    function ReceivedMessage(indexNumber) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "Default.aspx/ReceivedMessageByIndexNumber?indexNumber="+indexNumber,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var data = response.d;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    alert(data[i]);
                }
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                $('#output').text(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

Default.aspx :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool ReceivedMessageByIndexNumber(int textIndex)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=NotificationSystem;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT TextWord FROM TextProperty WHERE TextIndex = '" + textIndex + "'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your querystring parameter has a different name in the code (indexNumber) to name expected at the server the server (textIndex)

Comment: I do it but again same problem @major-mann

Comment: Did my answer work for you or what happened?  If it did work can you mark it as answer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a HTTP POST method but you are trying to pass the parameter like it is an HTTP GET.  I have never seen it written where you could specify the parameter in the URL like a HTTP GET.

Notice I add the JSON Data line below.  That is what fills your post request.

```
data: '{textIndex: "' + indexNumber + '" }',
```

**Entire Function:**

```
function ReceivedMessage(indexNumber) 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "Default.aspx/ReceivedMessageByIndexNumber",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{textIndex: "' + indexNumber + '" }',
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                alert(data[i]);
            }
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            $('#output').text(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did this work for you? If so it would be great for you to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a post request.so you need to add parameter in request body rather than url. so change your ajax call

```
function ReceivedMessage(indexNumber) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "Default.aspx/ReceivedMessageByIndexNumber?indexNumber="+indexNumber,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'textIndex': " + indexNumber+ "}",
            success: function (response) {
                var data = response.d;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    alert(data[i]);
                }
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                $('#output').text(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ReceivedMessage(indexNumber) 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Default/ReceivedMessageByIndexNumber/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { textIndex: indexNumber },
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response.d;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                alert(data[i]);
            }
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            $('#output').text(msg);
        }
    });
}
```